# Change default price filter behaviour for pwa in magento 2.3.4 using graphql

Tags: filter, magento2.3.4, pwa, graphql, aggregations

I have a requirement in which i need to customise the default price filter in magento and change the behaviour so that the price ranges will be constant and need to show all the ranges after a price filter is applied (eg: like in myntra, there the initial price ranges will be maintained all the time even after a price filter is applied, please see the image attached). But currently in magento when we apply a price range filter, next ranges will be the new ranges based on the current products list and initial ranges will not be shown.Is this possible to that the ranges to be fixed using graphql? i am using the aggregation do display the filters.

[image]

Comment: Did you find the solution?